# It is possible to read an object file?

Tags: c++, windows, compilation, compiler-construction, object-files

I was curious about `.obj` files: I pretty much don't know what they are (or what they contain), so I opened them with Vim text editor and what I found inside was an Alien like language...

Is there any way to understand what they represent and what is their content 
Also, for what are they being used ?

Thanks.

Comment: An object file is the output of a compiler. It's generally in binary and is meant to be understood by a linker, not by a human being. Why would wou want to open one?

Answer (score 10):

Sure.

But every different platform has a different object format.  On Windows, you could use a tool like [dumpbin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c.aspx) (dumpbin comes with Visual Studio).  On Linux, you could use "dumpobj", or disassemble the program.

Here's a good link for Linux:

http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/1060

PS:
objdump also lets you disassemble the object.  Like you used to be able to do with "debug" on DOS PCs...

Comment: I dont use visual studio I rather prefer CodeBlocks what I could do?

Comment: +1 for the link! The article provides a great deal of information regarding the elf format!

Answer (score 7):

The `.obj` files used by `link.exe` has MS COFF format.

You can find "Microsoft PE and COFF Specification" [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463119), and parse `.obj` file according to it.

Or, you can use existing tool like `dumpbin`.

Answer (score 5):

The [`readelf`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/readelf) tool is good at showing you *some* details on the data:

```
$ readelf -a /usr/bin/readelf
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF64
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           Advanced Micro Devices X86-64
...
```

Some of its abilities to inspect specific sections of the executable can come in handy too:

```
$ readelf -p .rodata /usr/bin/readelf | more

String dump of section '.rodata':
  [     4]  R_IA64_IMM14
  [    11]  R_IA64_NONE
  ...
  [  1f58]    Personality routine: 
  [  1f70]  __gcc_personality_v0
  [  1f85]  __gxx_personality_v0
  [  1f9a]  __gcj_personality_v0
  [  1faf]  __gnu_objc_personality_v0
  ...
```

Actually disassembling the code is a bit of a stretch; if you compile your code with `-g` for debugging symbols, you can use `readelf --debug-dump` to read the program source, type information, etc.

Comment: Very good response but im doing this on windows and I doubt it has those console options

Comment: Ahl yes, `readelf` really is for ELF files. Not so useful on Windows unless you're cross-compiling.